# Use Google Maps in Android without Google API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If you do not want to create your own Google API or have trouble creating one you can use a default key along with your package name and it will allow testing Google Maps...

Answer (score 0):

When you add a project with a Google Maps Activity, open google_maps_api.xml and replace the text "YOUR_KEY_HERE" with a temporary api key.

0F:6B:96:0B:A2:6D:CF:E1:CD:ED:A2:47:F4:48:C9:70:FB:AE:18:DE;YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME

Replace the text above (YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME) with your actual Package name. 
It should look similar to this:

0F:6B:96:0B:A2:6D:CF:E1:CD:ED:A2:47:F4:48:C9:70:FB:AE:18:DE;student.com.maps